# c# event handler after Serialport Write single byte

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, byte

I was wondering if this is possible to have some kind of an event handler in a separate thread/ process that fires when a single byte has been sent using comport.Write(...).

Please consider this part of code:

```
public SerialPort comport = new SerialPort("COM1", 38400, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);    
comport.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
```

Now lets say the buf.Lenght is 1000. My program stops untill i send all 1000 bytes.
I would not like to divide the comport.Write, i just want to use it once.

Is it possible now that everytime a byte is sent, some kind of event handler can turn on to for example update process bar etc, without interrupting the data sending to much (won't slow it).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Be careful with such a design.  If you send 1000 bytes and BeginInvoke for each one, that is a lot of Windows messages!  You would probably be better off updating some atomic int and polling it with a form timer to update your progress bar, every 500ms, say.

Comment: "I would not like to divide the comport.Write" - this seems contradictory. On the one hand, you don't want to split the data, on the other hand you want to have intermediate events. While you can prevent your GUI from freezing by putting all of the writing in another thread, you can only measure progress for every write call you make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SerialPort` class doesn't provide this out of the box, but you can add this functionality. Steps (written in notepad as metacode, you need to convert this to proper C# and add error handling, boundary condition and arguments checks)

#### Define an event

`public event Action BytesWritten;`

#### Define event invoker

`public void FireBytesWritten(){...}`

#### Define event handler

`public void OnBytesWritten(...){}`

#### Hook event to the event handler somewhere at init or set up code

`this.BytesWritten += OnBytesWritten;`

#### Now add a loop wrapping statement and fire an event when N bytes were written

```
SerialPort comport = new SerialPort("COM1", 38400, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);

int chunkSize = 1; // 1 byte for the chunk size
for(int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i += chunkSize)
{
    // Write small amount of bytes
    comport.Write(buf, i, chunkSize);
    
    // Fire an event saying that many bytes were written
    FireBytesWritten(...);

    //do checks for boundary conditions, add error handling if Write fails
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just create the event inside your class and fire it when appropriate.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Could you show me how would it do on an example please?
The point is i dont know how to specify when to fire the event.

Answer (score 0):

As you can easily see in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Ports.SerialPort%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), there is no such event in the built-in `SerialPort` class. But of course you could write your own method in a wrapper class which splits the message into smaller chunks and provides such an event. Of course there would be a small performance hit, but because the serial line is really slow, you won't feel it.